# When to use as_hidden in Django, and why not just display: none; in CSS?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm struggling to understand why and when you would make a form "hidden" in a Django app.

For example, when would you place a form in your template as

`{{ form.as_hidden }}`

and what is the practical difference between that, and placing it in a hidden `<div>`, like

```
<div style="display: none;">
     {{ form.as_hidden }}
</div>
```

?

Comment: You mean the difference between .as_hidden and `<div style="display: none;">{{ form.as_p }}</div>` ?

Comment: There is no as_hidden in django forms, there is a is_hidden for fields, which helps you determine if a field in a form is hidden or visible.

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't render entire forms as hidden so `{{ form.as_hidden }}` will not render anything.

Now if you want to talk about when to render [fields of forms](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5e06fa1469180909c51c07151692412269e51ea3/django/forms/forms.py#L582) `as_hidden`, then we're in business.

Why you want to render fields as hidden inputs (it's what `formfield.as_hidden` does) is when you want to send a value to the client, store and get it back to your view since they are sent back to the server when the form is submitted.